# Mean of quartile for multiple columns and multiple dates

Tags: r, loops, quartile

I'm trying to find the mean forward return (column fwd_rtn) of each quartile for each column (ie for quartiles for PB, PE, PS) for each date group (1/1/2016...1/4/2016)

```
head(df)
```

Date   Stock Price PB PE PS  fwd_rtn
1 1/1/2016 A 11.90 0.4    0.10  0.57 -0.015
2 1/1/2016  B  3.56 0.8    0.09  0.26 -0.036
3 1/1/2016 C  1.29 1.2    0.18  1.60  0.10
......
4 1/4/2016 A 12.80 0.39    0.13 0.53 -0.01
5 1/4/2016  B  4.03 0.76    0.08  0.23  0.02
6 1/4/2016 C  1.83 0.87   0.14  1.16  0.03

So far i have been able to find the mean return for 1 column for 1 date using this code

```
df$qPB <- cut(df$PB, breaks = quantile(df$PB, c(0,.25,.5,.75,1)),include.lowest = TRUE)  

aggregate(df$fwd_rtn,list(qPB = df$qPB),FUN=mean)
```

which gave me the right answers. But I'm struggling to do it for the multiple columns. I think I'm supposed to use `dplyr` and the `gather()` function but i dont know how.

Comment: Can anyone please drop me some crumbs/point me to a general direction as to how I can solve this please? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Can anyone please help me how to loop through using the apply function? Im very confused because of the finding quantile part..and then the aggregate. Its two parts so i should use the apply function on them both separately? How do i link the 2 parts? Any help is appreciated. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get quartiles of a single variable by date you can use the `ave` function:

```
df$qPB <- ave(df$PB, df$Date, FUN= function(i) cut(i, breaks = quantile(df$PB, 
                                          c(0,.25,.5,.75,1)),include.lowest = TRUE)
# a minor addition to aggregate
aggregate(df$fwd_rtn, list("qPB"=df$qPB, "date"=df$Date), FUN=mean)
```

You should take a look at using `lapply` or `sapply` to move through multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks lots lmo. It gave me an error at first but it was ok after i changed "date" = Date to "date"=df$Date. Next is how to use it for the multiple columns. Will attempt to use the lapply or sapply suggested.

Comment: sorry lmo i still cant get how to do it using lapply. but thats ok because I have been doing it individually (with the goal of cbinding the results at the end) ie for PS i did: df$qPS <- cut(df$PS, breaks = quantile(df$PS, c(0,.25,.5,.75,1), na.rm=TRUE),include.lowest = TRUE). Note that ive added a na.rm=TRUE, because there are some NaNs in PS. Wont this pose a problem when i cbind the results after going through all the columns?